two tables join with left join
i have two tables
table 1 : fiels (name)
table 2 : fields (name, number, residence, phone, etc...)
i want to join the two tables to include only the records from table 1 and the corresponding values from table 2, table 1 has 191463 records, table 2 has 188894 records.
i have tried the left join but the result hoin includes 197000 records

If you get more rows than there are in table 1, there must be multiples with the same name in table 2.

how can i do it to include the first occurence in table 2 please ?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Make it easy to help you!

Note that tables have rows and columns, not records or fields.

When you use a LEFT JOIN, it gets all rows from the table on the left and only rows from the right side that is equivalent, but when you have a relation between these columns and another column is different you will duplicate your rows by the same name but with different values in the column, example:
SELECT
   *
FROM person_names A
LEFT JOIN contacts B ON A.name = B.name;

It will return:

Are only 5 rows on the table "person_names", all being unique rows, but when I do the left join it returns 8 rows, why?
If you see, the match occurs but with 3 more rows from the left table (John Doe, Jane Smith, Bob Brown), that have the same name (used in condition) but have another differnt column value, for example the first name John Doe is diffent in the column "number", generating 2 rows
To solve this you will need to use a identifier, mostly a PRIMARY KEY to guarantee the properties (unique, not null, index), how you can do this in your dataset:
1 - Create the "id" column
Example of adding "id" to "person_names":
-- the ROW_NUMBER will product a integer starting with 1 until the last row of name
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS id,
    name
FROM person_names a;

2 - Adding constraint(primary key) for you "id" column
Example using "person_names" table:
ALTER TABLE person_names
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

Let me know if you need more help!
